# getting the error 'no member named 'Int32Ty' while trying to add a new instruction in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am new to llvm. I am trying to add a new instruction

```
namespace{
 struct insert:public FunctionPass{
 static char ID;
 insert():FunctionPass(ID){
 }
 bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override{
 errs()<<"Inserting new instruction\n";
 auto *pa = new AllocaInst(Type::Int32Ty,0,"new_inst");
 //auto *pa = new AllocaInst(llvm::Int32Ty, 0, "indexLoc");
 return false;
 }
 };
 }
 char insert::ID =0;
 static RegisterPass<insert>P("insert","inserting new instruction");
```

getting the error 
/Users/chandanj/llvm/llvm-9.0.0.src/lib/Transforms/Hello/Hello.cpp:89:33: error: no member named 'Int32Ty' in 'llvm::Type'
auto *pa = new AllocaInst(Type::Int32Ty,0,"new_inst");
                          ~~~~~~^

I a using macbook air. 
reading the llvm programmers manual

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for static [`Type::getInt32Ty()`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Type.html#a30dd396c5b40cd86c1591872e574ccdf) method.